# User deleting a row from a JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have created a program at work and have since been asked to add a feature to it. Currently the program:

1. Lets a user upload an XML file.
2. The XML file is parsed and saved into array lists.
3. A JTable is populated with data from the array lists.
4. The user can edit the JTable as they see fit and then click "save".
5. The data is put back into the XML file and it is saved under a new name.

While this works perfectly I have been asked to add a new feature, row deletion. Currently there are 60 columns generated in the JTable for any uploaded XML file (This program is for one specific type of XML file that always has 60 nodes that contain attributes). With an uploaded file however there may be any number of "transactions" that contain probably around 50-55 attributes. So the way that the table is populated if there were 5 transactions for example there would be 5 rows to the table.

So just to give a better explanation of the XML file (I can't share them as they contain sensitive information) we might have

```
<Group Tag (This only appears once in any XML)>
<Group Tag (This only appears once in any XML)>
<Transaction 1 (This contains about 55 sub-nodes with attributes)>
<Transaction 2 (This contains the same nodes as #1 with different attributes)>
```

I need to add the ability for a user to be able to delete one of these transactions (or rows) from the JTable, I have no idea how to do this. How can I delete an entire row? I'll post some of my code below to help you better understand what I'm working with..

GUI

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import mainClasses.MainClass;

import parsing.WriteParser;
import parsing.XMLParser;

public class MainGui 

{
    public static int counter;
    public static int counter2;
    public static JTable tbl;
    public static int currentRow;

    public static void createGUI(){

        counter=XMLParser.NtryRefAL.size();
        counter2=counter;

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("CamT54 Builder");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton uploadButton = new JButton("Upload");
        uploadButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        buttonPanel.add(uploadButton);

        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save Changes");
        saveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);

        //Creates the JTable
        tbl = new JTable();
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(){
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{

                    //Each true represents a column, there are 15 columns for each line of booleans. 
                    false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,
                    true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,
                    true,true,true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,
                    true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,
            };
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
                return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }
        };
        //Creates the column headers for all 60 columns. 
        String header[] = new String[]{"GrpHdr MsgRcpt Id", "GroupHdr CreDtTm", "GrpHdr MsgId", "Ntfctn Id", "Ntfctn CreDtTm",
                "Ntfctn Acct Id", "TxsSummry NbOfNtries", "TxsSummry Sum", "Ntry xmlns Sts", "Ntry Ref", "Ntry xmlns RsvlInd",
                "Ntry xmlns CdtDbtInd", "Ntry xmlns AddlNtryInf", "Ntry xmlns Amt Ccy", "TxDtls Amt Ccy", "TxDtls CdtDbtInd",
                "BkTxCd Cd", "Refs MsgId", "Refs PmtInfId", "Refs InstrId", "Refs EndToEndId","Refs TxId", "RltdPties InitgPty Id",
                "RltdPties Dbtr Nm", "RltdPties DbtrAcct Prtry", "RltdPties DbtrAcct Id", "RltdPties Cdtr Id", "RltdPties CdtrAcct Id",
                "RltdAgts DbtrAgt Cd", "RltdAgts DbtrAgt MmbId", "RltdAgts CdtrAgt Cd", "RltdAgts CdtrAgt MmbId", 
                "RltdAgts CdtrAgt Nm", "RmtInf RfrdDocInf Nb", "RmfInf RfrdDocInf Cd", "RmtInf Amt Ccy", "RmtInf CdtDbtInd", 
                "RmtInf AddiInf", "RmtInf Prtry", "RmtInf Ref", "RltdDts IntrBkSttlmDt", "RltdDts TxDtTm", "SplmtryData RmtCaptureDt",
                "SplmtryData RmtRcvdDt", "SplmtryData RmtProcDT", "SplmtryData PayInstrmnt", "SplmtryData PayTpCd", "SplmtryData PrimaryCustId",
                "SplmtryData EnrollmentId", "SplmtryData CardAcctTp", "SplmtryData PassThruData", "SplmtryData RmtRepresmtDt", 
                "SplmtryData RmtFinalDt","SplmtryData RunSettledDt", "SplmtryData RmtPaidDt", "SplmtryData ClrgMop",
                "SplmtryData ClrgAcct", "SplmtryData JobId", "SplmtryData NachaTransCd", 
                "SplmtryData TransTp"};

            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);

            tbl.setModel(dtm);




            for(int count = XMLParser.NtryRefAL.size(); count >0; count--){

                //Takes the data from the XML parser (that is saved into Arrays) and fills it into the 
                //table as new rows for each transaction. 
                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{XMLParser.MsgRcptS,XMLParser.CreDtTmS,XMLParser.MsgIdS,XMLParser.NtfctnIdS,
                        XMLParser.NtfctnCreDtTmS,XMLParser.AcctIdS,XMLParser.NbOfNtriesS,XMLParser.SumS,
                        XMLParser.StsAL.get(0),XMLParser.NtryRefAL.get(0),XMLParser.RsvlIndAL.get(0),XMLParser.CdtDbtIndAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.AddtlNtryInfAL.get(0),XMLParser.AmtCcyAL.get(0),XMLParser.TxDtlsAmtAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.TxDtlsCdtDbtIndAL.get(0),XMLParser.BkTxCdAL.get(0),XMLParser.TxDtlsMsgIdAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.PmtInfIdAL.get(0),XMLParser.InstrIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.EndToEndIdAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.TxIdAL.get(0),XMLParser.InitgPtyIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.DbtrAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.DbtrAcctPrtryAL.get(0),XMLParser.DbtrAcctIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.CdtrIdAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.CdtrAcctIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.ClrSysIdCdAL.get(0), XMLParser.MmbIdAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.CdtrAgtClrSysIdCdAL.get(0), XMLParser.CdtrAgtMmbIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.FinInstnIdNmAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.RfrdDocInfNbAL.get(0), XMLParser.RfrdDocInfTpAL.get(0), XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAmtCcyAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndAL.get(0), XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAddtlInfAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.CdtrRefInfTpAL.get(0), XMLParser.CdtrRefInfRefAL.get(0), XMLParser.IntrBkSttlmDtAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.TxDtTmAL.get(0), XMLParser.RmtCaptureDtAL.get(0), XMLParser.RmtRcvdDtAL.get(0), 
                        XMLParser.RmtProcDtAL.get(0), XMLParser.PayInstrmntAL.get(0), XMLParser.PayTpCdAL.get(0), 
                        XMLParser.PrimaryCustIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.EnrollmentIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.CardAcctTpAL.get(0), 
                        XMLParser.PassThruDataAL.get(0), XMLParser.RmtRepresmtDtAL.get(0), XMLParser.RmtFinalDtAL.get(0), 
                        XMLParser.RmtSettledDtAL.get(0), XMLParser.RmtPaidDtAL.get(0), XMLParser.ClrgMopAL.get(0),
                        XMLParser.ClrgAcctAL.get(0), XMLParser.JobIdAL.get(0), XMLParser.NachaTransCdAL.get(0), 
                        XMLParser.TransTpAL.get(0)});

                //Removes the first item in the array so the next 
                //item can be written during the second 
                //iteration
                XMLParser.NtryRefAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.AmtCcyAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtDbtIndAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.StsAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.AddtlNtryInfAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.BkTxCdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TxDtlsAmtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TxDtlsCdtDbtIndAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TxDtlsMsgIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.PmtInfIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.InstrIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.EndToEndIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TxIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RsvlIndAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.InitgPtyIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.DbtrAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.DbtrAcctIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.DbtrAcctPrtryAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrAcctIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.MmbIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.ClrSysIdCdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.FinInstnIdNmAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrAgtMmbIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrAgtClrSysIdCdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RfrdDocInfNbAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RfrdDocInfTpAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAmtCcyAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAddtlInfAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrRefInfTpAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CdtrRefInfRefAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.IntrBkSttlmDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TxDtTmAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtCaptureDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtRcvdDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtProcDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.PayInstrmntAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.PayTpCdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.PrimaryCustIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.EnrollmentIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.CardAcctTpAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.PassThruDataAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtRepresmtDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtFinalDtAL.remove(0); 
                XMLParser.RmtSettledDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.RmtPaidDtAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.ClrgMopAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.ClrgAcctAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.JobIdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.NachaTransCdAL.remove(0);
                XMLParser.TransTpAL.remove(0);



            }

            tbl.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);


            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(12).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(13).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(14).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(15).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(16).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(17).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(18).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(19).setPreferredWidth(280);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(20).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(21).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(22).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(23).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(24).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(25).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(26).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(27).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(28).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(29).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(30).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(31).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(32).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(33).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(34).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(35).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(36).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(37).setPreferredWidth(200);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(38).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(39).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(40).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(41).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(42).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(43).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(44).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(45).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(46).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(47).setPreferredWidth(200);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(48).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(49).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(50).setPreferredWidth(600);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(51).setPreferredWidth(200);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(52).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(53).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(54).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(55).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(56).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(57).setPreferredWidth(150);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(58).setPreferredWidth(200);
            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(59).setPreferredWidth(150);



            //Allows the user to upload a new XML file which will be parsed
            //and the table will be populated. 
            uploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    FileHandling fHandling = new FileHandling();
                    fHandling.getFile();
                    XMLParser parse = new XMLParser();
                    parse.parseXML();
                    frame.dispose();
                    MainGui.createGUI();
                }
            });

            //Allows the user to save the edited table. All table values will be saved 
            //back into the initial arrays (which are now empty), which will then 
            //be parsed into a new array.
            saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    currentRow=0;

                    if(null != tbl.getCellEditor()){
                        tbl.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                    }

                    while(counter2>0){
                        XMLParser.MsgRcptS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 0));
                        XMLParser.CreDtTmS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 1));
                        XMLParser.MsgIdS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 2));
                        XMLParser.NtfctnIdS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 3));
                        XMLParser.NtfctnCreDtTmS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 4));
                        XMLParser.AcctIdS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 5));
                        XMLParser.NbOfNtriesS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 6));
                        XMLParser.SumS.equals(tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 7));
                        XMLParser.StsAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 8));
                        XMLParser.NtryRefAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 9));
                        XMLParser.RsvlIndAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 10));
                        XMLParser.CdtDbtIndAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 11));
                        XMLParser.AddtlNtryInfAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 12));
                        XMLParser.AmtCcyAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 13));
                        XMLParser.TxDtlsAmtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 14));
                        XMLParser.TxDtlsCdtDbtIndAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 15));
                        XMLParser.BkTxCdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 16));
                        XMLParser.TxDtlsMsgIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 17));
                        XMLParser.PmtInfIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 18));
                        XMLParser.InstrIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 19));
                        XMLParser.EndToEndIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 20));
                        XMLParser.TxIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 21));
                        XMLParser.InitgPtyIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 22));
                        XMLParser.DbtrAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 23));
                        XMLParser.DbtrAcctPrtryAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 24));
                        XMLParser.DbtrAcctIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 25));
                        XMLParser.CdtrIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 26));
                        XMLParser.CdtrAcctIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 27));
                        XMLParser.ClrSysIdCdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 28));
                        XMLParser.MmbIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 29));
                        XMLParser.CdtrAgtClrSysIdCdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 30));
                        XMLParser.CdtrAgtMmbIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 31));
                        XMLParser.FinInstnIdNmAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 32));
                        XMLParser.RfrdDocInfNbAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 33));
                        XMLParser.RfrdDocInfTpAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 34));
                        XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAmtCcyAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 35));
                        XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 36));
                        XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnAddtlInfAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 37));
                        XMLParser.CdtrRefInfTpAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 38));
                        XMLParser.CdtrRefInfRefAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 39));
                        XMLParser.IntrBkSttlmDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 40));
                        XMLParser.TxDtTmAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 41));
                        XMLParser.RmtCaptureDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 42));
                        XMLParser.RmtRcvdDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 43));
                        XMLParser.RmtProcDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 44));
                        XMLParser.PayInstrmntAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 45));
                        XMLParser.PayTpCdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 46));
                        XMLParser.PrimaryCustIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 47));
                        XMLParser.EnrollmentIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 48));
                        XMLParser.CardAcctTpAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 49));
                        XMLParser.PassThruDataAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 50));
                        XMLParser.RmtRepresmtDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 51));
                        XMLParser.RmtFinalDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 52));
                        XMLParser.RmtSettledDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 53));
                        XMLParser.RmtPaidDtAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 54));
                        XMLParser.ClrgMopAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 55));
                        XMLParser.ClrgAcctAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 56));
                        XMLParser.JobIdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 57));
                        XMLParser.NachaTransCdAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 58));
                        XMLParser.TransTpAL.add((String) tbl.getValueAt(currentRow, 59));





                        currentRow++;
                        counter2--;

                    }


                    WriteParser wParser = new WriteParser();
                    wParser.reWrite();


                }

            });


            panelNorth.add(tbl);
            panelNorth.add(new JScrollPane(tbl));
            panelNorth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            panelSouth.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            mainPanel.add(panelNorth,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            mainPanel.add(panelSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.add(mainPanel);

            frame.setVisible(true);
```

XML Parser

(I won't post the entire code because it's quite long but I populate array lists with parsed data like this: )

```
XPathExpression PrimaryCustIdexpr = xpath.compile("//Ntfctn/Ntry/NtryDtls/TxDtls/SplmtryData/Envlp/Cnts/PrimaryCustId");
            Object PrimaryCustId = PrimaryCustIdexpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodesPrimaryCustId = (NodeList) PrimaryCustId;
            for(int i = 0; i < nodesPrimaryCustId.getLength(); i++){
                Element PrimaryCustIdel = (Element) nodesPrimaryCustId.item(i);
                PrimaryCustIdS = Utilities.xmlToString(PrimaryCustIdel);
                int length = PrimaryCustIdS.length();
                PrimaryCustIdS = PrimaryCustIdS.substring(53,length);
                length = PrimaryCustIdS.length();
                PrimaryCustIdS = PrimaryCustIdS.substring(0,length-16);
                PrimaryCustIdAL.add(PrimaryCustIdS);

            }
```

WriteParser (This is just an example of how I save data back to the XML)

```
XPathExpression AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndexpr = xpath.compile("//Ntfctn/Ntry/NtryDtls/TxDtls/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocAmt/AdjstmntAmtAndRsn/CdtDbtInd");
            Object AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtInd = AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndexpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodesAdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtInd = (NodeList) AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtInd;
            for(int i = 0; i < nodesAdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtInd.getLength(); i++){

                nodesAdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtInd.item(i).setTextContent(XMLParser.AdjstmntAmtAndRsnCdtDbtIndAL.get(i));

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Default Table model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has on its API a removeRow method.

Depending on how you want to access the rowIndex (ie. SelectionListener vs. JTable.getSelectedRow), you can use that method to update the table.

#### Edit

For pseudocode:

```
// Access the currently selected row.
int rowIndex = tbl.getSelectedRow();

// -1 denotes no row selected, check against that.
if (rowIndex >= 0){
    // Remove the row from the table.
    dtm.removeRow(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: So what your saying is that if I added say an extra button called "delete row" I could then use .getSelectedRow.removeRow or something along those lines and this would allow me to delete the row?

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is what I'm looking for!